# Class and instance

Tags: c#, .net

I am doing an exercise about a flight and customer class. I was wondering about for the method under flight class which is used to add passenger (using customer Manager class ). How should I add this method to add customer in the flight class but using the method in the customer manager class?

[image]

```
class CustomerManager
{
    public static int currentCxNum;
    private int numCxs;
    private int maxCxs;
    private Customer[] myList;

    public CustomerManager(int seed, int maxCx)// seed=starting point
    {
        currentCxNum = seed;
        maxCxs = maxCx;
        myList = new Customer[maxCx];
    }

    public bool addCustomer(int cID,string fN, string lN, string cNum)
    {
        if (numCxs >= maxCxs)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            Customer a = new Customer(cID, fN, lN,cNum);
            currentCxNum++;
            myList[numCxs] = a;
            numCxs++;
            return true;
        }
    }
}

class Flight
{
    protected int flightNum, masSeats, numPassengers;
    protected string origin, destination;
    protected CustomerManager[] cxList;

    public Flight(int flNum, string orig, string dest, int maxSe)
    {
        flightNum = flNum;
        origin = orig;
        destination = dest;
        masSeats = maxSe;
    }

    public bool addPass(Customer cx)
    {
        CustomerManager bb = new CustomerManager(100,200);
        if (numPassengers <= masSeats)
        {
            if (!bb.customerExist(cx.getID()))
            {
                bb.addCustomer(cx.getID(), cx.getfName(), cx.getlName(), cx.getcxNum());
                numPassengers++;
            }

            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want to do is instead of having an array of `CustomerManager` objects you have one `CustomerManager` object per `Flight` object. The `CustomerManager` object then manages a list of `Customer` objects. So then the `Flight` object's `addPassenger` method would take a `Customer` and then call the `CustomerManager`'s `addCustomer` method. Something like:

```
public class Flight
{
    protected int flightNum;
    protected string origin, destination;
    protected CustomerManager cxList;

    public Flight(int flNum, string orig, string dest, int maxSe)
    {
        cxList = new CustomerManager(0, maxSe);
        origin = orig;
        destination = dest;
        flightNum = flNum
    }

    public bool addPass(Customer cx)
    {
      return cxList.addCustomer(cx.getCID(),cx.getFN(), cx.getlN(),cx.getcNum());
    }

}
```